# jQuery UI Sorting Bootstrap Labels

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to add ordering ability to a bunch of tags in my app. I this:

```
$('.__sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: '.__sortable',
    opacity: 0.8,
});
```

Which seems to work allowing me to sort between multiple containers. When I drop it I see it works.

However, as I'm dragging I don't get any feedback showing me the position it "would" snap into. On their demo page you can see the items in the list actually moving.

Having trouble achieve the same. They are just a bunch of inline `label` elements from bootstrap

```
<label class="label label-warning">some text</label>
```

Comment: What are you using? [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) or another? If this is the case, you should provide a CSS class to the placeholder option.

Comment: Thx, didn't realize I had to style it up myself a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to style it up myself a bit. Adding `display: inline-block` made it work. It also helps to `0` out the heights as I was getting some extra white space above.

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
    display: inline-block !important;
    height: 0px !important;
    line-height: 0px !important;
    font-size: 0px !important
}
```